# Pass a parameter into a Powershell script in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: powershell, jenkins

There are previous questions regarding passing a Jenkins variable into a powershell script.  But they are not working for me.  It might be the way I am running the powershell script.
This is the code:

```
steps{
    script {

        echo "release file name: " + "$env:RELEASE_NAME"        
        powershell('''
            Write-Host "Deploy into WTC production"
            Write-Host "Release file: $env:RELEASE_NAME"        
            $finalPath = $env:RELEASE_NAME
            
            ...more powershell statements....
            
            ''')
        }
```

The echo statement returns the correct filename with version and .zip extension
the Write-Host command returns an empty string for the release name

I tried adding `withEnv([releaseName=$env:RELEASE_NAME])` to the top of the powershell script like this:

```
withEnv([releaseName=$env:RELEASE_NAME])
powershell('''
                Write-Host "Deploy into WTC production"
                Write-Host "Release file: $env:releaseName"
```

But the file does not compile because of the :.
How do I pass the RELEASE_NAME variable into the powershell script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out...
missing double quotes around withEnv...
Final Answer:

```
script {

                    echo "release file name: " + "$RELEASE_NAME"
                    withEnv(["releaseName=$RELEASE_NAME"]){
                    powershell('''
                        Write-Host "Deploy into WTC production"
                        Write-Host "Release file: '$env:releaseName'"
```